# Recommendation for website monitoring service that tests with real browser?

Tags: monitoring

I need a recommendation for a online website monitoring service (like https://www.uptrends.de, not self hosted) for javascript heavy websites with [threejs](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_cubes) (3d canvas). The monitoring should inform me (by email) if the website (a given url) is down or if it takes too long to fully load. Because most of the website is dynamic and relies on a 3d canvas, the criterion that the website "is not down" == "fully loaded" is that the javascript part of the website runned successfully. For this, the javascript adds a special class to the body tag of the website ("app-ready"). The website is "fully loaded" only after the body tag has a class "app-ready". Because the website relies on a 3d canvas, the monitoring service can not run it in headless mode, it would need a real browser.

Does such a online monitoring service exist?

Comment: Ever consider using something like Selenium to have Firefox, Chrome, etc open the webpage and look for things after certain timeouts, etc.

Comment: I need a online service like https://www.uptrends.de, not a self hosted solution (I asked the question on serverfault.com, it was moved to software recommendations automatically..)

Answer (score 0):

I've used StatusCake in the past for personal sites as it has a free tier that should do both things you're looking for and is pretty configurable with email notifications. It also has a page speed test, but the free tier only allows 1 test per 24 hours so that might not work so great if you're looking to go free only.

Comment: I asked them and "unfortunately at this point it's something we can't support. ", so no, StatusCake is not an option